# Problem while trying to create users in Ubuntu 14.04 64bits version

Tags: 64-bit, 14.04, freeze, users, adduser

My problem began when I tried to create a new user in GUI mode. When I click on "users accounts" in "System configuration" the window changes to black and stops responding. I tried to reinstall the OS but the problem continues.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit version).

Comment: You have to be root to add users as far as I know. If you just want to add a regular user, you can use the command `sudo adduser THE_USER_NAME`. Check `man adduser` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you first open the *User Accounts* window, the options are usually restricted. You should click the "Unlock" button in the top right corner, and you will be prompted for your password (this is `gksudo`, the graphical version of `sudo`).

Enter your password, and the **+**/**-** buttons should now be available for you to create a new account.

Comment: @jkt123 thanks for the edits. I don't know why my `code` markup isn't working. New 14.04 Ubuntu-Gnome install, maybe something is smart-quote switching or something?